# Is there a spoke light that is ultrabright?

Tags: wheels, safety, product-rec, lighting

I love the setup [this guy demos here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmAqXP3OTuA) as it is attention-grabbing and is visible from all directions, however I'm wondering what options I have with ultrabright spoke lights.

The description says they are testing the Serfas Thunderbolt. Can the Serfas Thunderbolt be securely mounted to spokes, or is the demo merely a party trick?

Comment: This is a shopping question and likely to be closed.

Comment: I'd expect it would unbalance the wheel.  I prefer spoke reflectors.

Answer (score 0):

the thunderbolt comes stock with rubber straps, basically long-lasting rubber bands. the bike in the video has aerospokes, which would be thick enough to keep the light well secured.  aerospokes are uncommon though; typical wheels have 32-36 2mm steel spokes, which wouldn't provide much to grab onto.

there are plenty of other spoke lights out there which are designed for 2mm spokes.  i would check what kind of wheel you have before you go buy anything.

Comment: Ah, I somehow missed that he was using aerospokes. I guess it would be harder for Thunderbolts to grab onto my standard spokes.